# How would I calculate two given pixels to obtain its aspect ratio?

Tags: css, aspect-ratio

I've looked online on how to get the aspect ratio to write proper media queries for a website I'm trying to make but some of these numbers don't make sense.

What I'm trying to do is take two pixels, say, 667 x 325.  I put those two numbers inside the website below, but result I'm getting is 667 : 325.  I don't think that's correct, or is it?

https://aspectratiocalculator.com/

I've also tried looking for a mathematical formula to get these so I can just manually do these but there are so many out there that don't fit into the context of what I'm trying to obtain.

How can I get the aspect ratio of two given pixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aspect ratio is width / height, e.g. 600 by 800 = 600/800 = 0.75.

The calculator is correct because the "Ratio" by conventional meaning of the word is 600:800 or 0.75:1 or 0.75 (as we programmers use it)

Comment: A formula as an equation will not contain `:`. The visual representation of a ratio is `2:1` which means for every 2 on the left, there's 1 on the right, which the formula is derived as `2 / 1` (just replace the `:` with a division)

Comment: I realise now that the `x` in 600 x 800 can be VERY misleading, interpret that as `by` so 600 (wide) BY 800 (high)